# OctoberCMS translation (with translate plugin) of preloaded list of records

Tags: list, translate, octobercms

question is very simple, is there a quick way to translate a preloaded list in db. For example list of towns/countries?

```
class SeedTownTable extends Seeder
public function run()
{

    $town_list = array(
        'Акко',
        'Арад',
        'Ариэль',
        'Афула',
        'Ашдод',
        'Ашкелон',
        'Бат-Ям',
        'Бейт-Шеан',
        'Бейт-Шемеш',
        'Бейтар-Илит',
        'Беэр-Шева',
        'Бней-Брак',
        'Герцлия',
        'Гиват-Шмуэль',
        'Кирьят-Малахи',
        'Кирьят-Моцкин',
        'Кирьят-Оно',
        'Кирьят-Тивон',
        'Кирьят-Хаим',
        'Кирьят-Шмона',
        'Кирьят-Ям',
        'Кфар-Саба',
        'Лод',
        'Маале-Адумим',
        'Маалот-Таршиха',
        'Метула',
        'Мигдаль-ха-Эмек',
        'Модиин',
        'Ход-ха-Шарон',
        'Холон',
        'Цфат',
        'Эйлат',
        'Эльад',
        'Явне',
        'Яффо'
    );  

    foreach ( $town_list as $town ){
        Town::create([
            'name' => $town
            ]);
    }

}
```

I made towns model with records without any backend controller.
And I want to translate this list.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the translation to your data array and use `setAttributeTranslated` to add the translated version.

As mentioned in the Docs

> // Gets a single translated attribute for a language
>
> $user->getAttributeTranslated('name', 'fr');
>
> // Sets a single translated attribute for a language
>
> $user->setAttributeTranslated('name', 'Jean-Claude', 'fr');

Try

```
$town_list = array(
    [ 
        'name'                      => 'Town Name Default Lang',
        'name-es'                   => 'Town Name in Spanish',
    ]
    ...
)

foreach ( $town_list as $town ){
        $t = new  TownModel(); 
        $t->name = $town['name'];
        $t->setAttributeTranslated('name',  $town['name-es'], 'es');
        $t->save();
}
```